# Alt-Tab issue on Windows Activation in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, events, key

In my app, I have a special action mapped to the tab key. The problem is that when you use the short-cut Alt-Tab to switch between different apps, my app gets a tab key (but not the Alt key) when it becomes activated, which I'd like to avoid. This happens sometimes (not all the time), especially when you switch apps very fast.

I could filter it out by checking `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt)`, but my app doesn't get the Alt-key in this case. Any tip?

Comment: I think [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) can help.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, Ramin, but in general, I'd like to avoid Global Hook which may slow down the system a little bit, and some anti-virus programs even filter out the apps with global hook, as I read.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to detect Alt and Tab when your program is activated via Alt-Tab?

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue where KeyUp event handler doesn't register `e.Key == Key.LeftAlt`. Instead I had to use `e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt`. Perhaps you are facing a similar issue (although I don't know if you use the KeyUp/KeyDown event handler)?

Another thing to try would be `Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt` or maybe even `KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt` inorder to filter out *Alt*.